# Expanding dict value using keys in the same dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion, set

I try to expand the values of a dictionary using keys in the same dictionary. In other words, I try to replace `dic` values (existing set with another/ potentially expanded set). The expansion happens when the value contains a key in the dictionary.

Input:

```py
dic = {
    '10': {'01', '02'},
    '11': {'03', '04'},
    '20': {'05', '10'},
    '21': {'06', '11'},
    '30': {'07', '20'},
    '40': {'08', '21', '30'},
    '50': {'09', '40'}
}
```

Expected output:

```py
{
    '10': {'01', '02'},
    '11': {'03', '04'},
    '20': {'05', '01', '02'},
    '21': {'06', '03', '04'},
    '30': {'07', '05', '01', '02'},
    '40': {'08', '06', '03', '04', '07', '05', '01', '02'},
    '50': {'09', '08', '06', '03', '04', '07', '05', '01', '02'}
}
```

I was trying to create a recursive function...

```py
def transform_dic(d):
    def func(k):
        v = d.get(k, k)
        if v != k:
            for e in v:
                v = func(v)
        return v
    d2 = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        d2[k] = {func(i) for i in v}
    return d2

print(transform_dic(dic))
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'

Comment: Why are you trying to hash a set?

Comment: This is not my intention. I try to replace dict values (existing set with another/expanded set)

Comment: Note that your function both modifies `d` and returns `d`. In python there has been an effort to make functions that either build a new version without modifying the original, or modify the original without having a return value. For instance, if `l` is a list, then `l.sort()` sorts `l` without returning anything, and `sorted(l)` returns a sorted list without modifying `l`.

Comment: @MohitC , Stef - I have added another variable to return without modifying the original, but it still results in an error

Comment: @ZygD, I dont know if theres something else in your code which is over-writing this, but if you just copy the code you posted in a separate file you will see its running successfully without any error and generating output too

Comment: @MohitC - I pasted it into Google Colab. It highlights this line: `v = d.get(k, k)` with the same error. Have you  done something to that line?

Comment: When you do `v = func(v)`, `v` is a set, so you're calling `func` on a `set`. That's what causes the error, because the first thing you do in `func` is call `d.get(k)` where `k` is that set. Presumably you want to do something like `v.remove(e); v.update(func(e))` instead of `v = func(v)`.

Comment: https://ideone.com/cv90Xd

Comment: Also note that your function will run into an infinite loop (or a RecursionError) if the input dict is "circular"; for instance `dic = {1: {2}, 2:{1}}`

Comment: @MohitC - that shared example uses expected output dict as input

Comment: sorry my bad...

Comment: @ZygD where are you using `e` from `for e in v`

Comment: @MohitC - you're correct, I haven't used it. But it I fix it and do `v = func(e)`. I still don't get the expected output. The script was my "best" attempt. I don't think I can ,correct the question now, as many comments are about the error. If fixed, the error is gone, but the expected output is not there.

Comment: You can update the question by removing error and posting the output you are getting. But i think this should give you enough scope to debug. Print the values and iterate through the recursion manually. You'll get to it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things that you want to expand recursively are the sets in the dict, not the dict itself. You always only have one dict.

For this reason, I believe it's easier to write a recursive function to expand a set, and then use this function to expand the dict.

```py
def expanded_dict(d):
    return {k: expanded_set(v, d) for k,v in d.items()}

def expanded_set(s, d):
    return {
        y
        for x in s
            for y in (expanded_set(d[x], d) if x in d
                      else (x,))
    }
```

Note that `expanded_set` returns a new set without modifying the input set nor the input dict; and `expanded_dict` returns a new dict without modifying the input dict.

It's good practice to make it clear whether your function returns a new object, or modifies the input object. For instance, `sorted` returns a new list without modifying its input, whereas `list.sort` modifies a list without returning anything.

Here is a function which expands a dict by modifying it without returning anything:

```py
def expand_dict(d):
    stable = False
    while not stable:
        stable = True
        for k in d:
            for x in list(d[k]):
                if x in d:
                    d[k].remove(x)
                    d[k].update(d[x])
                    stable = False
```

Testing with your examples:

```py
dic = {
    '10': {'01', '02'},
    '11': {'03', '04'},
    '20': {'05', '10'},
    '21': {'06', '11'},
    '30': {'07', '20'},
    '40': {'08', '21', '30'},
    '50': {'09', '40'}
}

print(expanded_dict(dic))
# {'10': {'01', '02'}, '11': {'03', '04'}, '20': {'01', '05', '02'}, '21': {'03', '06', '04'}, '30': {'07', '01', '02', '05'}, '40': {'04', '06', '08', '05', '02', '01', '07', '03'}, '50': {'04', '06', '08', '02', '05', '01', '07', '09', '03'}}

print(dic)
# {'10': {'01', '02'}, '11': {'03', '04'}, '20': {'10', '05'}, '21': {'11', '06'}, '30': {'07', '20'}, '40': {'08', '30', '21'}, '50': {'40', '09'}}

expand_dict(dic)
# no return value

print(dic)
# {'10': {'01', '02'}, '11': {'03', '04'}, '20': {'01', '02', '05'}, '21': {'03', '06', '04'}, '30': {'01', '05', '07', '02'}, '40': {'04', '06', '08', '05', '02', '01', '07', '03'}, '50': {'04', '06', '08', '05', '02', '01', '07', '09', '03'}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over output dict and check if values inside the set is member of result dict or not:

```python
from typing import Dict, Set


dic = {
    '10': {'01', '02'},
    '11': {'03', '04'},
    '20': {'05', '10'},
    '21': {'06', '11'},
    '30': {'07', '20'},
    '40': {'08', '21', '30'},
    '50': {'09', '40'}
}

output = {
    '10': {'01', '02'},
    '11': {'03', '04'},
    '20': {'05', '01', '02'},
    '21': {'06', '03', '04'},
    '30': {'07', '05', '01', '02'},
    '40': {'08', '06', '03', '04', '07', '05', '01', '02'},
    '50': {'09', '08', '06', '03', '04', '07', '05', '01', '02'}
}

def conv(d: Dict[str, set[str]]) -> Dict[str, set[str]]:        
    result: Dict[str, set[str]] = {}
    for k,vs in d.items():
        result[k] = set()
        for v in vs:
            if v in result:
                for t in result[v]:
                    result[k].add(t)
            else:
                result[k].add(v)
    return result

print(conv(dic))
print(conv(dic)==output)
```

the output will be

```python
{'10': {'02', '01'}, '11': {'03', '04'}, '20': {'02', '05', '01'}, '21': {'06', '03', '04'}, '30': {'02', '05', '07', '01'}, '40': {'05', '03', '02', '01', '06', '07', '08', '04'}, '50': {'05', '03', '09', '02', '01', '06', '07', '08', '04'}}
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be recursive?

```
def transform_dic(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        for n in set(v):
            if n in d:
                d[k].remove(n)
                d[k].update(d[n])

transform_dic(dic)
print(dic)
```

If you don't want to modify the original dictionary use `deepcopy`

```
def transform_dic(d):
    d = deepcopy(d)
    for k, v in d.items():
        for n in set(v):
            if n in d:
                d[k].remove(n)
                d[k].update(d[n])
    return d

print(transform_dic(dic))
```

Output:

```
{
    '10': {'01', '02'},
    '11': {'03', '04'},
    '20': {'01', '05', '02'},
    '21': {'03', '04', '06'},
    '30': {'01', '07', '05', '02'},
    '40': {'01', '08', '07', '04', '06', '03', '05', '02'},
    '50': {'01', '08', '07', '04', '06', '03', '05', '02', '09'}
}
```